# When trying to swipe the screen from bottom to top till the end of the page but the swipe is not happening in appium

Tags: selenium, appium

I was trying to find an element using swipe using the touch action class but The Appium server is throwing an error that there is a problem from the command.I was trying to use the touch action class using the coordinates to move from one place to another.My code looks as follows:

```
 @Test(priority=4)
 public void selectprod()
 {

drivertest.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     WebElement categ= drivertest.findElementsByName("See All").get(1);
    categ.click();

        TouchAction abc=new TouchAction(drivertest);
        abc.longPress(479, 754).moveTo(0, -500).perform();

            if (drivertest.findElement(By.name("Pragnya Manufacturer")).isDisplayed())
            {
                drivertest.findElement(By.name("Pragnya Manufacturer")).click();

            }
       }
```

The server is throwing this error as follows:

> The Server did not respond Error

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 improvements that i can tell you right away:

1. MOST Important - try never to use Implicit wait.

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); //60 is the wait time in seconds
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
   ```
2. please use this block of code for your scrolling, change the `starty` and `endy` to changing scrolling length and direction.

   ```
   public void scrollDown() 
   {
       Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
       int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.7);
       int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.2);
       int startx = size.width / 2;
       driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 800);
   }
   ```
3. The function `isDisplayed()` will throw an Exception if the element is not visible, please surround it with `try` and `catch`.
4. You scroll just one time, maybe the element is located lower in the table, i would advise to make a `for()` loop (don't forget to add a limit to the scroll iterations)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void swipeLeft(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver)
    {
        Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize(); 
        int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.8); 
        int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.16); 
        int starty = (int)(size.height * 0.75); 
        driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 1000);
    }
```

hope this will help